# eth0 not in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, dhcp, static-ip

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my ethernet (eth0) connection is working fine. (with DHCP)

However, when I read the `/etc/network/interfaces`, there is nothing about `eth0` in it.

Is Ubuntu 14.04 reading the eth0 settings from somewhere else?

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I want to set my eth0 with a static address but I don't understand why there is there nothing about eth0?

Answer (score 0):

What version of your Ubuntu ? workstation(desktop) or server edition ? If your Ubuntu version is workstation do not type script in **/etc/network/interfaces**, it can be make your network manager not works . Use the network manager to set static ip in your system . open terminal -> type : nm-connection-editor -> chose your interfaces which to edited -> settings -> ipv4 -> method -> static . Look at the picture to use network manager .

[image]

Comment: yes, it is workstation(desktop).